# string_t from(wstring OR string) when string_t can also be typedef of both

Tags: c++, string, templates, metaprogramming, overloading

```
namespace settings{
  typedef wchar_t char_t;
  typedef std::basic_string<char_t> string_t;
}

namespace util{
  namespace string{
    std::basic_string<wchar_t>  toWide(const std::basic_string<char>&      s);
    std::basic_string<char>     fromWide(const std::basic_string<wchar_t>& w);
  }
}
```

This is what I've. `char_t` may be `wchar_t` or `char`. Now I want two functions that intelligently convert the input string `settings::string_t`

```
settings::string_t  from(const std::basic_string<char>& s);
settings::string_t  from(const std::basic_string<wchar_t>& s);
```

using `boost::is_same` doesn't work on `return s` because **string_t typedef'ed as wstring but returns string**

```
settings::string_t util::string::from(const std::basic_string< char >& s){
  if(boost::is_same< std::basic_string<char> , settings::string_t >::value){
    return s;
  }else{
    return toWide(s);
  }
}
```

It is east to identify whether `InputType` and `string_t` is same or not using template as well as overloads, but If they are not same then there comes 4 variations.

How to model this scenario **without overloading type operator** ?

### Summary

How can I design the `settings::string_t from(const std::basic_string<T>& s);` that converts both `char` and `wchar` strings to `string_t`. Where T can also be `char` or `wchar_t`. and you can see in the question `string_t` is flexible. it can also be both `char` or `wchar_t` strings

Comment: How can I design the `settings::string_t from(const std::basic_string<T>& s);` that converts both `char` and `wchar` strings to `string_t`. Where T can also be `char` or `wchar_t`. and you can see in the question `string_t` is flexible. it can also be both `char` or `wchar_t` strings

Comment: "How to model this scenario without overloading type operator ?"  What do you mean by this?

Comment: Sorry If I am not clear enough what I want is `settings::string_t from(const std::basic_string<T>& s)` that converts both char and wchar strings to string_t

Comment: I believe the problem is that you would have to provide 4 conversions: from char to char, from char to wchar, from wchar to wchar and from wchar to char. OP is trying to avoid those 4 checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remove all of the overloads, as you have different functions to convert each direction.  I used a template specialization of a structure, but it should be possible to do it with overloads as well.

The helper class (and it's specializations) can easily be placed in a namespace to move it so it's not as visible to the user (for an example, see any of the `detail` namespaces under boost).  Also, it will fail to compile if some combination is used without providing the necessary specialization.

```
template<typename FromCharT, typename ToCharT>
struct helper;

// If T is the same on both sides, just copy
template<typename T>
struct helper<T, T>
{
   static std::basic_string<T> convert(const std::basic_string<T>& s)
   {
      return s;
   } 
};

// char -> wchar_t
template<>
struct helper<char, wchar_t>
{
   static std::basic_string<wchar_t> convert(const std::basic_string<char>& s)
   {
      return toWide(s);
   } 
};

// wchar_t -> char
template<>
struct helper<wchar_t, char>
{
   static std::basic_string<char> convert(const std::basic_string<wchar_t>& s)
   {
      return fromWide(s);
   } 
};


template<typename T>
settings::string_t from( const std::basic_string<T>& f)
{
   return helper<T, settings::char_t>::convert(f);
}
```

Comment: Basically, it would involve an overload that passes through `string_t from(const string_t&)`, and then a pair of overloads that use `boost::enable_if` and `boost::is_same` that chooses which to use based on the current `settings::char_t`.  I don't have time to type it up myself.